# Fatal error on include of existing header

Tags: c++, include

When i try to work with the Fastor-Library(https://github.com/romeric/Fastor) and i include the library, i get the error, that a folder inside the repo does not exist. Is this an error on my behalf, or should i open an issue with the author of Fastor?

Code:

```
#include "Fastor/Fastor.h"

int main(){
    Fastor::Tensor<double,2> A;
    return 0;
}
```

Folder structure:

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 15 name name 4096 Feb 13 13:19 Fastor
-rw-r--r--  1 name name   82 Feb 13 13:20 main.cpp
```

Why do i get the following error?

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -mavx -DNDEBUG main.cpp -o main
In file included from Fastor/simd_vector/SIMDVector.h:4:0,
                 from Fastor/Fastor.h:6,
                 from main.cpp:1:
Fastor/simd_vector/simd_vector_base.h:4:10: fatal error: commons/commons.h: No such file or directory
 #include "commons/commons.h"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Are you able to reproduce the error, or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: ```Fastor``` is the cloned repo, it contains ```commons/commons.h```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compiler command should be:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O3 -mavx -DNDEBUG main.cpp -o main -I Fastor
```

And you should just include `"Fastor.h"` rather than `"Fastor/Fastor.h"`.

Comment: This fixed it, though i have to wait 7 minutes to accept your answer